# Integrate Kal Calendar in Customized tabbed Panel in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am developing an application, which has following scenario.
After user logged into application, a customized tabbed panel will appear.
I want to display Kal Calendar into my First tab Item.
But Failed in doing so.
Please anybody can provide me precise steps for XCODE 4.2 it will be grateful..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3):

Add `TapkuLibrary` to your project (TapkuLibrary.bundle and other header files)

```
#import "TKCalendarMonthView.h"
```

Include these delegates:
`TKCalendarMonthViewDelegate`,`TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource` (in .h file)

Declare `TKCalendarMonthView *calendar;` in interface declaration file (i.e. .h file)

`@property (nonatomic, retain) TKCalendarMonthView *calendar;` (in .h file)

`@synthesize calendar;` (in .m file)

AND then in `viewDidLoad`

```
calendar = [[TKCalendarMonthView alloc] init];
calendar.delegate = self;
calendar.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:calendar];
[calendar reload];

- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {
    NSLog(@"calendarMonthView didSelectDate");
}

- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView monthDidChange:(NSDate *)d {
//  NSLog(@"calendarMonthView monthDidChange"); 
//  NSLog(@"d is %@",d);
}
```